# Can two conditions be defined in single CASE statement in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case

My BigQuery Sample table has 3 columns ErrorDesc,SalesNo,SalsesNokey
task is to assign value 'abc' to salesNo when SalesNokey is '§§' and to set the errordesc as 'unknown value'

The output should look like this :

| SalesNokey | SalesNo | ErrorDesc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| §§ | abc | unknown value |
| 200 | valid | No error |

My case statement looks like this:

```
CASE  
WHEN SalesNokey = '$$$$$$'
THEN abc
ELSE
SalesNokey
END
```

Not sure how to define ErrorDesc in the same case statement..or is there a better conditional statement i can use in Bigquery? Any help appreciated.
note: All the columns are already defined and hence I am unable to use END AS ErrorDesc(creates a new column)

Answer (score 0):

You would use two `case` expressions, one for each column to transcode. You can alias the new columns with the same name as the original columns.

```
select SalesNokey,
    case when SalesNokey = '§§' then 'abc'           else SalesNo   end as SalesNo,
    case when SalesNokey = '§§' then 'unknown value' else ErrorDesc end as ErrorDesc
from mytable
```

If you are looking for an `update` statement, that actually changes the values in the table:

```
update mytable
set SalesNo = 'abc', ErrorDesc = 'unknown value'
from mytable
where SalesNokey = '§§'
```

Comment: Thank you but this is still creating new columns SalesNo and ErrorDesc ..these columns are already present in the table and I have to just assign the corresponding values to them

Comment: @Codepy: you seem to want an `update` query. See my updated answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case of if statemant:

```
SELECT SalesNokey
,IF(SalesNokey = '§§', 'abc', SalesNo) as SalesNo   
,IF(SalesNokey = '§§', 'unknown value', ErrorDesc) as ErrorDesc
FROM `bigquery.tables.sample`
```

If you want to use CASE statement you can:

```
SELECT SalesNokey
,CASE 
 WHEN SalesNokey = '§§' 
 THEN 'abc' ELSE SalesNo 
END as SalesNo
,CASE 
 WHEN SalesNokey = '§§' 
 THEN 'unknown value' ELSE ErrorDesc
END as ErrorDesc
FROM `bigquery.tables.sample`
```

Comment: Thank you but this is still creating new columns SalesNo and ErrorDesc ..these columns are already present in the table and I have to just assign the corresponding values to them

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the update statement then you can try this :

```
Update mytable
set SalesNo = CASE WHEN SalesNokey = '§§' then 'abc' else 'valid' end,
    ErrorDesc = CASE WHEN SalesNokey = '§§' then 'unknown value' else 'No error' end;
```